# FCK Editor Spell Check Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fckeditor

When clicking on spell check the following error is occuring

```
undefined method `full_sanitizer' for FckeditorController:Class
```

in the popup window

> Rails Version 2.3.2
>
> FCk Editor Version 0.4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I included the following code in
>   fckcontroller class.Then the problem
>   solved.

```
include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
extend ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper::ClassMethods
```

[This Link](http://www.undefinedrange.com/2009/03/13/reusing-rails-2-2-2-strip_tag-view-helper)helps